# SyntaxError in Python robot controller code

Tags: python, python-2.7

I’m using [approxeng.input.selectbinder](https://approxeng.github.io/approxeng.input/) for a robot controller and 
`def __init__(self, *requirements, print_events=False, **kwargs):` 
throws up a `SyntaxError`, specifically the `print_events` statement. I cannot understand why. This is the full code that gives the error:

```
from functools import reduce
from select import select
from threading import Thread

import approxeng.input.sys as sys
from approxeng.input.controllers import *

EV_KEY = 1
EV_REL = 2
EV_ABS = 3


class ControllerResource:
    """
    General resource which binds one or more controllers on entry and unbinds the event listening thread on exit.
    """

    def __init__(self, *requirements, print_events=True, **kwargs):
        """
        Create a new resource to bind and access one or more controllers. If no additional arguments are supplied this
        will find the first controller of any kind enabled by the library. Otherwise the requirements must be provided
        as a list of ControllerRequirement

        :param requirements:
            ControllerRequirement instances used, in order, to find and bind controllers. If empty this will
            be equivalent to supplying a single unfiltered requirement and will match the first specified controller.
        :param print_events:
            Defaults to False, if set to True then all events picked up by the binder will be printed to stdout. Use
            this when you're trying to figure out what events correspond to what axes and buttons!
        :param kwargs:
            Any addition keyword arguments are passed to the constructors for the controller classes. This is useful
            particularly to specify e.g. dead and hot zone ranges on discovery.
        :raises ControllerNotFoundError:
            If the requirement can't be satisfied, or no requirements are specified but there aren't any controllers.
        """

        self.discoveries = find_matching_controllers(*requirements, **kwargs)
        self.unbind = None
        self.print_events = print_events

    def __enter__(self):
        """
        Called on entering the resource block, returns the controller passed into the constructor.
        """
        self.unbind = bind_controllers(*self.discoveries, print_events=self.print_events)
        if len(self.discoveries) == 1:
            return self.discoveries[0].controller
        else:
            return tuple(discovery.controller for discovery in self.discoveries)

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        """
        Called on resource exit, unbinds the controller, removing the listening thread.
        """
        self.unbind()


def bind_controllers(*discoveries, print_events=False):
    """
    Bind a controller or controllers to a set of evdev InputDevice instances, starting a thread to keep those
    controllers in sync with the state of the hardware.

    :param discoveries:
        ControllerDiscovery instances specifying the controllers and their associated input devices
    :param print_events:
        Defaults to False, if set to True then all events picked up by this binder will be printed to stdout
    :return: 
        A function which can be used to stop the event reading thread and unbind from the device
    """

    discoveries = list(discoveries)

    class SelectThread(Thread):
        def __init__(self):
            Thread.__init__(self, name='evdev select thread')
            self.daemon = True
            self.running = True

            self.device_to_controller_discovery = {}
            for discovery in discoveries:
                for d in discovery.devices:
                    self.device_to_controller_discovery[d.fn] = discovery
            self.all_devices = reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, [discovery.devices for discovery in discoveries])

        def run(self):

            for discovery in discoveries:
                discovery.controller.device_unique_name = discovery.name

            while self.running:
                try:
                    r, w, x = select(self.all_devices, [], [], 0.5)
                    for fd in r:
                        active_device = fd
                        controller_discovery = self.device_to_controller_discovery[active_device.fn]
                        controller = controller_discovery.controller
                        controller_devices = controller_discovery.devices
                        prefix = None
                        if controller.node_mappings is not None and len(controller_devices) > 1:
                            try:
                                prefix = controller.node_mappings[active_device.name]
                            except KeyError:
                                pass
                        for event in active_device.read():
                            if print_events:
                                print(event)
                            if event.type == EV_ABS or event.type == EV_REL:
                                controller.axes.axis_updated(event, prefix=prefix)
                            elif event.type == EV_KEY:
                                # Button event
                                if event.value == 1:
                                    # Button down
                                    controller.buttons.button_pressed(event.code, prefix=prefix)
                                elif event.value == 0:
                                    # Button up
                                    controller.buttons.button_released(event.code, prefix=prefix)
                except Exception as e:
                    self.stop(e)

        def stop(self, exception=None):

            for discovery in discoveries:
                discovery.controller.device_unique_name = None
                discovery.controller.exception = exception

            self.running = False

    polling_thread = SelectThread()

    # Force an update of the LED and battery system cache
    sys.scan_cache(force_update=True)

    for device in polling_thread.all_devices:
        device.grab()

    def unbind():
        polling_thread.stop()
        for dev in polling_thread.all_devices:
            try:
                dev.ungrab()
            except IOError:
                pass

    polling_thread.start()

    return unbind
```

Comment: You appear to be using one or more libraries that are not part of standard Python, but have not identified what they are.

Comment: Please provide the context around the code you are asking about.  (And `print_events` isn't a statement.)

Answer (score 2):

**Minimal Reproducable Example**

The following is a [Minimal Reproducable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the issue in the question:

```py
class ControllerResource:

    def __init__(self, *requirements, print_events=True, **kwargs):
        pass
```

With Python 3.x this compiles just fine (i.e. you can import it without errors)., but with Python 2.x this raises a SyntaxError:

```
  File "test.py", line 3
    def __init__(self, *requirements, print_events=True, **kwargs):
                                                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

**Explanation**

The reason is that the argument list contains a regular (keyword) argument (i.e. `print_events=True`) after a varargs argument (i.e. `*requirements`).

In Python 3.x this is valid, and it would make the argument `print_events` a keyword-only argument (See [PEP 3102](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3102/) for more information and examples). Python 2.x does not support keyword-only arguments and thus the above code is not valid in Python 2.x.

**Solution**

First of all, I would highly recommend to use Python 3.x when possible, since Python 2.x is very old and it's not being maintained anymore after [January 1, 2020](https://pythonclock.org/).

However, if you really *must* use Python 2.x for whatever reasons, you could reorder the arguments for the `__init__` method as follows:

```py
class ControllerResource:

    def __init__(self, print_events=True, *requirements, **kwargs):
        pass
```